# iPhone gui message from perl/shell-script possible?

Tags: iphone, perl, shell

I want to write a perlscript on my iPhone that is able to give me a heads up at certain points so I'm wondering how I would go about doing that.
Is there a way to get a message through the gui from a script running in the background? I've been looking without much luck. I had a thought about inserting a fake sms into the sqlite db as a last resort but it seems somewhat unlikely that it would work.
It would be nice to be able to make a push notification style popup appear but that might too much to ask.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution I liked so I decided to share it. I found an app for jailbroken iPhones called [GriP - Growl for iPhone](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/GriP). Which changes the way push notifications and other messages are handled. It also makes it possible to send messages from the command line via something along the lines of:

> `/usr/bin/GriP -t "Title" -d "Description"`

It has worked great so far.
Thank you for your help TechZen and molecules.

Answer (score 4):

For reasons of security and stability, Apple does not allow scripting languages on the iPhone. You can run them on a jailbroken phone but I'm given to understand it's a hassle.

From the [Apple Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html):

> Note: On a desktop system, a
>   background process is often the means
>   whereby users are informed of
>   downloadable data for an application
>   that currently isn’t running. But on a
>   device such as the iPhone, background
>   applications are, for performance and
>   security reasons, prohibited. Only one
>   application may be executing at a
>   time.

The iPhone is a secure and reliable phone first and a computer second. Computing is sacrificed to ensure a reliable phone.

Comment: Yeah it is jail-broken. And I have installed perl and made some scripts so that part is done. I just want to know if there is a way to talk to the gui directly or indirectly.

Comment: There are no scripting hooks built into the iPhone API. However, Objective-C is very open to scripting so it might be possible to whip something up. There are 3rd party scripting tools for MacOs such a F-script that give complete access to all Objective-c APIs but that don't depend on any special hooks within the API itself. You might look at F-script which IIRC is open source and see how they do it. Then you could try to apply that to the iPhone OS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want information from your phone itself or from an outside source? If you want information from an outside source, you could set up a Perl script on a computer to e-mail yourself notifications (see [Sending Email with Perl Best Practice](http://www.revsys.com/writings/perl/sending-email-with-perl.html)).

Comment: I would really prefer to have the iphone do all the work but you make a good point, guess I could resort to that if nothing else works.